# Login Error while connecting to SQL Server 2008 with new user login

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I installed a SQL Server 2008 database server and created a user. But when I try to login for the same user through SQL Authentication I get this error:

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)

P.S : I have already SQL Server authentication through properties. Please guide. I am trying to connect through SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: **Which** edition of SQL Server did you install? Did you pick a specific **instance name** (or did you just use the defaults)? What **server/instance name** are you trying to use to connect to it ??

Comment: I have installed the enterprise edition. I didnt pick any instance and went ahead with the defaults.

Comment: And what **server / instance name** are you using to try to connect to it??

Comment: I created a user on this server and gave all the rights. I opened SQL Server Management Studio and tried to login with this username. I found this error.

Comment: It is telling you there is nothing running at the other end, so have you checked the services are running? and that the pipe transport is enabled?

Comment: I have posted the error above..and i checked for shared memory, tcp/ip, named pipes are all enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve above mention in the post by performing the below activities.

Firstly

1. When you open the `management studio`, Right click on the `server` and click on the `properties`. In the `security` section by default only windows authentication is on, make sure SQL Authentication is also on clicking the radio button which has the option to enable both Windows and SQL Authentication.
2. Go to `Configuration Tools` --> `SQL Server Configuration Manager`. Check the `protocols`. The ordering should be

   (i) Shared Memory(Enabled)

   (ii) TCP/IP(Enabled)

   (iii) Named Pipes(Enabled)

Restart the SQL Server Services Instance

Restart your machine.

And it should work fine.